# Implement functionality for all the UIViewControllers using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Is there a way to implement functionality for all the `UIViewControllers` ?

I'm trying to extend a specific behavior for all the UIViewControllers, is very standard.

For example:

**MyBaseClass**

```
class MyBaseClass {
    public func load(viewController:UIViewController){
        print("The size of the view is \(viewController.view.size.width)")
    }
}
```

I have to implement a similar behavior among 100 `UIViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use protocols in combination with an extension to `UIViewController`.

Define your behavior as a protocol and extend `UIViewController` to implement it:

```
protocol WidthProtocol {

    func showWidth()

}

extension UIViewController: WidthProtocol {

    func showWidth() {
        print("The width of the view is \(self.view.frame.size.width)")
    }

}
```

Once you have that in place, you can call your function from any subclass of `UIViewController`, such as:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Show the width
        showWidth()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to call a the same function in all your view controller you can just subclass it:

```
class YourCustomViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("The size of the view is \(view.frame.width)")
    }

}
```

then just replace `UIViewController` by `YourCustomViewController`:

```
class oneOfYour100Controler : UIViewController {
```

to something like that:

```
class oneOfYour100Controler : YourCustomViewController {
```

Then you don't need to do anything, the message will be print automatically.

Comment: Subclassing UIViewController is a bad idea. Use protocol extensions or create a simple helper class.

Comment: In general or in that case? In that case it would be a bad idea indeed (I feel like it was for debug reasons). In general it really depends on why you are subclassing.